# Why did the engineers leave the map to their military base planet?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

*Prometheus* starts with the finding of the cave paintings of a star map. Shaw and Holloway had interpreted it as an invitation.

In the further action it occurs that the place pointed to by the map was actually a military base with ships full of mass destruction weapons pointed to Earth.

Why would the engineers show humanity the way to their weaponry?

Comment: Related: [How is this "star map" supposed to work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153591/prometheus-star-map) and cross site dupe on M&TV: [What is the real purpose of the star map in Prometheus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2813/45378)

Comment: Please do not delete duplicate questions, [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/345161).

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question.